# Repetindo código na hora de listar

Tags: java

Estou com um problema de repetição na hora de listar, na minha *view* ele repete R01 e R01, duas vezes o mesmo código e somente depois ele segue corretamente R02, RO3 e assim por diante. O correto seria R01, R02, R03 e assim vai. Valeu.

```
public void reorganizarNumerosItens() {
    List<Listitem> itens = this.getItems();

    if (itens != null) { 
        int i = 1;
        for (Listitem itemAtual : itens) {
            ListitemRequisitoFuncional itemReq = (ListitemRequisitoFuncional) itemAtual;
            RequisitoFuncional requisitoFuncional = itemReq.getReqFuncional();
            requisitoFuncional.setStrNumRequisito(this.getStrNumItemAtual(i));
            i++;
            itemReq.recarregaObjeto();

            try {
                this.bo.salvar(requisitoFuncional);
            } catch (NegocioException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public String getStrNumItemAtual(Integer numItem) {
     if (numItem == 0) {
        numItem +=1; 
    }
    String strNumItem = numItem.toString();
    strNumItem = strNumItem.length() < 2 ? "R0" + strNumItem : "R" + numItem;

    return strNumItem;
}
```

Comment: apenas um comentário, os arrays comencam em 0 (zero) mas voce mete a variavel `i` a comecar em 1. Uma vez dentro da funcao, voce tem `if(numItem == 0)` mas isso nunca vao acontecer, pois está a passar o primeiro como `1`... troque para `int i = 0;`

Comment: Nesse caso ele está usando a variável "i" para setar o numRequisito, por isso ele começa de 1. R01, R02, R03, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver dessa forma, veja um exemplo aqui também: https://ideone.com/1ucEGY

```
    numItem +=1;
    String strNumItem = numItem.toString();
    strNumItem = strNumItem.format(strNumItem, numItem) != null ? "RF0" + strNumItem : "RF" + numItem;

    return strNumItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitua o seguinte trecho de código:

```
requisitoFuncional.setStrNumRequisito(this.getStrNumItemAtual(i));
```

por

```
String aux = "R00".substring(0,"R00".length()-String.valueOf(i).length())+String.valueOf(i);

requisitoFuncional.setStrNumRequisito(aux);
```

Isso vai eliminar a função **getStrNumItemAtual**. Provavelmente nela está o seu problema.

Comment: Não deu certo não, fiz esse procedimento mas não deu certo. Continua listando mas repetindo os dois primeiros campos.

Comment: @FredericoQueiroz, existe um outro problema aí, certamente não é na definição do código então. Se você imprimir a variável aux logo após criá-la, o código repete?

Comment: Sim os dois primeiros RO sim. RO1, RO1 RO2.

Comment: @FredericoQueiroz, se você fizer isso: "String aux = "R00".substring(0,"R00".length()-String.valueOf(i).length())+String.valueOf(i); System.out.println(aux);" o código repete?

Comment: Sim, continua, vou ter que analisar aqui com calma.

Comment: Sinceramente, não vejo como isso acontecer. Para isso ocorrer a sua variável "i" deveria decrementar em algum ponto ou então, por alguma razão, não ser incrementada. Tratamento de exceção não é, pois se uma exceção for lançada antes do i ser incrementado, a execução do for é interrompida.

Comment: De boa, valeu pela ajuda amigo.